# How to display dropdown menu slider effect from bottom to top after hover?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I have display drop down menu slider effect from bottom to top after hover with linearly and all drop down text should be display left align.
    I tried some code but when i hovered first menu my second menu displaying on right side.would you help me in this?

**HTML**

```
<div class="right-menu-bar">
        <ul class="main-menu">
            <li><a href="">Menu</a>
                <ul>
                <li><a href="">menu1 details</a></li>
                <li><a href="">menu1 details</a></li>
                <li><a href="">menu1 details</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
<li><a href="">Menu</a>
            <ul>
            <li><a href="">menu1 details</a></li>
            <li><a href="">menu1 details</a></li>
            <li><a href="">menu1 details</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

**CSS**

```
.right-menu-bar ul.main-menu > li
{
    float: left;
    margin: 15px;
    font-size: 16px;
}
li ul
{
    list-style: none;
    background: #3498db;
    z-index: 2;
    font-size: 16px;
    padding:0 ;

}

li ul li
{

    text-transform: capitalize;
}

.main-menu li > ul {
    display:none;

}

.main-menu li:hover > ul {
    display:block;
}


li ul li a{
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 10px 50px;
  display:block;

text-align: left !important;
}

 li ul li a:hover{
  background-color:#5dade2;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thought your problem is stop the second menu slide to right when hover the 1st menu. so adding the position:absolute property to dropdown menu to avoid the second menu sliding.

Now I am adding sideDown() and slideUp() to show or hide the dropdown on menu hover Try below code.

```js
 //Hide and Show The Sub Menus
  $(".jquery-test ul li.menu-list").hover(function(){
   $(this).find('ul').stop().slideDown();
  },function(){
   $(this).find('ul').stop(true,true).slideUp();
  });
```

```css
.jquery-test ul.menu li.menu-list{display:inline-block;padding-right:20px;}
.jquery-test ul{list-style:none;padding-left:10px;}
.jquery-test ul.menu li.menu-list ul.submenu {display:none;}
.jquery-test ul.menu li.menu-list ul.submenu{position:absolute;}
.jquery-test ul.menu li.menu-list ul.submenu li{position:relative;left:0px;}
.jquery-test ul li a{text-decoration:none;color:#000;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="jquery-test">
 <ul class="menu">
  <li class="menu-list"><a href="#">Menu1</a>
   <ul class="submenu">
    <li><a href="#">Menu1.0</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Menu1.1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Menu1.2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Menu1.3</a></li>
   </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="menu-list"><a href="#">Menu2</a>
   <ul class="submenu">
    <li><a href="#">Menu2.1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Menu2.2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Menu2.3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Menu2.4</a></li>
   </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="menu-list"><a href="#">Menu3</a>
   <ul class="submenu">
    <li><a href="#">Menu3.0</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Menu3.1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Menu3.2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Menu3.3</a></li>
   </ul>
  </li>
 </ul>
```

Comment: Mr.Dhaarani...You solved my one issue.Please help me in second.I  have to slide dropdown form bottom to top when hover.

Comment: @Hybreeder Now check the code. Hope It will solve your problem

Comment: Sorry for late reply...Its working for me.Thanks Mr.Dhaarani

Comment: @Hybreeder It's okay. If any doubt or clarification on above code let me know.

Comment: Mr.Dhaarani Only one doubt how can i display drop down text on left site.

Comment: @Hybreeder remove the padding left 10px in this line .jquery-test ul{list-style:none;padding-left:0px;}

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by applying `position: absolute;` to the menus that appear, like this:

```
.main-menu li:hover > ul {
    display:block;
    position: absolute;
}
```

[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/c1hxkey2/)

Comment: Mr.Bassie...You solved my one issue.Please help me in second.I have to slide dropdown form bottom to top when hover.